# jQuery math on selection change

Tags: jquery

So using jQuery I was able to figure out how to change the value of HTML in a span on change with a selection drop down, but it's a bit hacky.  Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/flinx777/ZMjun/

Currently I'm grabbing the class from the selection chosen and replacing the text in the span with the class value.  Instead I'd prefer to define the span HTML (define the price of the product here) and when someone chooses from the selections, it either adds or subtracts from the price.  So for example I'm trying to make the selection HTML like this:

```
<select id="price_change" name="buckle options">
<option value="" class="">Please select</option>
<option value="Stainless steel" class="">Stainless Steel</option>
<option value="Titanium" class="+20">Titanium</option>
<option value="No Buckle" class="-10">No Buckle</option>
</select>
```

This way I can define in the class in the selection options to either add or subtract from the product price (which is in the span) as opposed to the current way I'm doing it of having to manually do the math in the selection as I'm doing now.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to have multiple products on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fft7G/

but in my opinion, it is stange to set price in class

Comment: hey Benoit, thanks for that jsfiddle...works great. instead of class, what you recommend?  i can easily switch it out.  I just changed it to "data-offset" as Daniel A. White recommended in the response above this and it worked.  excuse my ignorance, but why is using class bad?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the property "value"

```
<select id="price_change" name="buckle options">
    <option value="135" >Please select</option>
    <option value="135" >Stainless Steel</option>
    <option value="155" >Titanium</option>
    <option value="125" >No Buckle</option>
</select>
```

Change the code that you proposed to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Changes the price on the page if a selection is made with a price modifier
    $("#price_change").change(function() {
        var price = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        $(".product_price").html(price);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you use the value property, then when you post the form, those values will be posted, not the names of options

Answer (score 4):

You should make these `data-` attributes, not a `class`.

```
<select id="price_change" name="buckle options">
<option value="" data-offset="0">Please select</option>
<option value="Stainless steel" data-offset="0">Stainless Steel</option>
<option value="Titanium" data-offset="+20">Titanium</option>
<option value="No Buckle" data-offset="-10">No Buckle</option>
</select>
```

Then you can do.

```
var offset = parseInt($(someSelector).data('offset'), 10);
```

Comment: Be careful with data- and numbers.  I believe it truncates leading 0s, causing data-offset=0 to be data-offset="" when retrieved.

Comment: @Mully then `parseInt` will return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This works
http://jsfiddle.net/Vw5Ms/5/

But man, this is soooo dirty